# PHP - mysqli connect from localhost(my local PC) to amazon EC2 hosted database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, amazon-ec2

I have tried to **connect to Amazon EC2 instance MySql from localhost**.

Tried:

- Granting privilege for user for remote connect
- Made domain ping-able from outside.
- Able to login through phpmyadmin with same credentials
- Gone through lot of Stackoverflow answers.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('ec2-12-223-36-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'myuser', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
// mysqli_connect('domain', 'myuser', 'pasword', 'dbname', 3306);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect');
}

echo 'Connected successfully';
exit;
```

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Comment: By `localhost`, do you actually mean you are trying to connect from your local PC to the Amazon cloud

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes exactly

Comment: Are you sure that your ec2 port 3306 is open to public?

Comment: This would require your database on EC2 to be exposed to the public internet. 1) You'd need to set it up this way, and 2) this is a terrible idea security wise. You typically tunnel into your EC2 machine using SSH and connect to the database through the tunnel.

Comment: How can I connect from Google cloud to EC2 database then? @deceze

Comment: Make your question about exactly *that*.

Comment: @deceze Currently am trying to do what is on question - If it's possible, I will try it in cloud as well

Comment: Are you sure you set proper setting to connect from outside? like bind address on my.cnf and correct host on myuser account?

Comment: @huhushow  Yes, I tried  adding bind-address as mentioned in some article

Comment: There is already solution please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344057/connect-to-mysql-on-aws-from-local-machine